# Twisted Vivaldi

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, lateral-thinking, anagram

There are 5 riddles. Each riddle will lead to a one word clue for the final answer. Your job is to guess the final answer. The problem is, each riddle has a twist:

1 of them is a red herring.

1 of them is an anagram.

1 of them has either an extra letter or a missing letter.

1 of them has a one letter difference.

1 of them stays the same.

> 1.
>   You give me to a worker, when they do a good job
>   I am one end of a pencil or a sword
>   If you do this to a glass of water, the water spills.
>   
>   2.
>   I am used to tell the time,
>   Although I am also in your body;
>   I have a child used to stop,
>   They are exactly half of me.
>
> 3.
>   You see me gliding through the air,
>   or you crunch me on the ground.
>   Sometimes I hold on as hard as I can,
>   until the wind comes and blows me away.
>
> 4.
>   I'm on the ground when you walk out your door,
>   You'll meet me in the forest if you choose to explore,
>   I'm not red, blue, or even brown,
>   If you want to see me, you'll have to look down.
>
> 5.
>   You collect me in Minecraft,
>   I am very general,
>   I am a category,
>   Re-arranged, I spell TIME.

What is the overall answer?

Hint:

> Each answer is singular

Comment: I'm disappointed that "red herring" doesn't seem to fit any of these riddles. :(

Comment: How could you use red herring to relate to something else? Unless red herring was the red herring :)

Comment: Maybe, I will give hints as time goes on

Comment: In regard to $4)$ I would have guessed *feet* but they can be brown, depending on your skin colour. They can also be red or blue (metaphorically speaking) if you are wearing red/blue shoes...

Comment: @ZaniXu would it be possible to respond to some of our answers below or provide another hint? I'd like to continue solving your riddle but it seems progress has halted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a feeling this riddle is too broad to be solved, but here’s my best go:

> The answer is a flower. Or fruit, or the season of spring. I derive this from PIT, LEAF, STEM, and SOW, all words that have to do with planting seeds and growing flowers and whatnot. The answer seems very ambiguous, but at least ties back to Vivaldi’s Four Seasons. Beside, trying to get one answer per season really feels like shoehorning.

My operations on each riddle’s answer:

1)

> The answer, tip, is an anagram of PIT, as that of a peach or other fruit.

2)

> The answer, hand, is a red herring.

3)

> The answer, leaf, stays the same.

4)

> The answer, snow, loses a letter to become SOW. This riddle could also be ROCK, GRASS, or really anything you find on the ground outside that isn’t dirt.

5)

> The answer, item, changes one letter to become STEM.

Comment: Congratulations! This is correct.

Answer (score 3):

1)

> Tip

2)

> Finger [Half is fin, or stop/ending]

3)

> Leaf

4)

> Shadow

5)

> Item

Comment: Welcome to puzzling.SE! Any idea for the final answer?

Comment: Thanks! Not sure yet, I'm trying to get the individual words first before attempting the final answer.

Answer (score 3):

My answer :

> Donna Noble, one of the Tenth Doctor's companions in Doctor Who

My reasoning :

The riddle's title points me towards

> TV series

because

> Vivaldi wrote *The Four Seasons*, TV series are divided into seasons. Also as @cpcodes pointed out in the comments, the initials of Twisted Vivaldi are TV

Assuming the answers to the riddles are as follow :

> 1) TIP
>  2) FINGER (@Logikable)
>  3) LEAF
>  4) SHADOW
>  5) ITEM

I get the following words by applying the twists :

> TRIP (TIP plus one letter)
>  TIME (ITEM anagram)
>
>  These two together hint towards Doctor Who
>
>  GINGER (FINGER with one letter difference)
>
>  This hints towards either Donna Noble or Amy Pond
>
>  SHADOW (stays the same)
>
>  LEAF is the red herring here

The answer is deduced by :

> This last word points towards the episode *Silence in the Library* where the Vashta Nerada appear as shadows. Donna was the Doctor's companion in that episode.

Comment: Can you explain how the title is related to your answer?

Comment: @Logikable Done

Comment: Also: gur gvgyr'f vavgvnyf ner GI

Comment: @cpcodes Nice ! I did not notice that. I got the idea because of rot13(gur anzr bs nabgure nafjrere : QbpgbeKBE)

Comment: Too bad there is no Knowledge or trivia tag. It is a nice find, but with that show, you can link almost any word to fit a random episode.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how to change these answers but I found:

Number 1

> Tip

Number 3

> Leaf

Number 4

> ?

Number 5

> Item (TIME  ->  ITEM)

Comment: 2 of them are correct, the other is VERY close

Answer (score 2):

Number 2

> Hand(s)

Which fits the first 3 lines.

Comment: Fits also the 4th line (fingers are half the length of a hand) but unfortunately we were told in another comment that this answer is wrong

Answer (score 0):

I have another answer for

2. > A **sundial**.

`I am used to tell the time,`

> A sundial is used to tell the **time**.

`Although I am also in your body.`

> Sundials use **shadow** to tell the time, much like what humans have.

`I have a child used to stop,`

> The child is **direction** as you have to position the sundial correctly, where it would 'stop' and remain still.

`They are exactly half of me.`

> *They* are **North** and **South**. Without them, sundials would be inaccurate; you might say that *half* of their accuracy is dependent on how it is positioned, the other half is how it is built.

Comment: I think in `They are exactly half of me`, "`they`" is a genderless way to refer to the child mentionned in the above line

Comment: @LioraHaydont I see, but I could not think of anything else, so I just made the "`child`" a bit broad (like direction) to try and getaway with the analogy.